# How do I programmatically determine my PowerApps release number and the version of my own app?

Tags: versioning, powerapps

I have seen online various functions attempting to determine my PowerApps release number and the specific version for my canvas app, but none have worked for me. Do you know how to obtain my Power Apps release version number, and my specific app version number?

This is the best I've found so far but it only outputs a a version date that doesn't even accurately reflect my last published app version. Maybe it is the PowerApps release date, but that's still not what I want:

- First(Filter(PowerAppsforMakers.GetApps().value, properties.displayName = "YourAppName")).properties.appVersion

NOTE: You have to fill "YourAppName" with your specific app name. Also, to be able to use the above function and have your app compile, then starting from the top menu in your PowerApps editing session, you have to go to "View" | "Data sources" | "Add data source", and then click "New connection". Search for "Power Apps for Makers" and sign in as required.

Comment: After looking deeper, I couldn't find an appVersion other than the timestamp you mentioned. You *could* convert the timestamp to a number by wrapping your function in  `Text()`. (Ex: `Text(<your-function>, "")`). This results in Unix time. Not very *human* readable, but may suffice for you.